# Keep minimized windows in focus? Alt. minimize toggle

Tags: unity, 16.04, shortcut-keys

I use `<ALT>+DOWN` to minimized a window to my launcher. I'd like to however toggle `<ALT>+DOWN` again to restore it. The normal behavior of ubuntu makes it lose focus of the window when minimizing so when I press `<ALT>+DOWN` again the next window focused on is also minimized.

Anyway to set this? I'm basically wanting a toggle for minimizing.